How to set MacOS Sonoma password that was accidentally set to blank
I was delivered a MacStudio for work. It runs MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1. Our IT technician set up a password for me on it and asked me to change it. I went to change it but accidentally left the new password blank, and confirmed when prompted. Now I can access the account without a password, but the "System Settings/Users and Group" dialog does not allow me to set a new password. It prompts me for the old password, which doesn't exist anymore. I have admin rights, so I feel like I should be able to set a new password. How do I set a new password.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102673

As a shortcut, you could try the passwd(1) shell command, which you might have to run as root with sudo; e.g., sudo passwd [username]

So I feel very stupid and I am tempted to delete this post, but in case anyone was as stupid as me:
The dialog asks you to verify your password a little bit further down and I had not understood that you're supposed to type your new password twice. If you type your new password twice, it will work.

There’s no need to be hard on yourself. We all have busy days and miss something - not knowing and learning is actually a good sign of intelligence and adaptability. Would you be willing to self answer your question. People will learn and a screen shot will help visual learners !

I had to verify my password by typing it again a little bit lower in the dialog. And then it worked! It was not immediately clear to me because I was expecting the verification input to be closer to the first input.
